# (Solved) CiviEvent mandatory key missing error

Tags: civievent, drupal

Drupal 7, Civi 5.12: 
On submitting a live event booking I receive the following error:
*Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: one of (activity_name, activity_type_id, activity_label)*

The booking does update in Civi (both event and contribution) but the confirmation email and invoice do not get sent.

Any ideas please?

[image: backtrace]
[image: Fatal error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon said, its difficult to say. But its certainly because of com.pesc.sparkpost extension. I believe the extensions is creating activity of type 'Transactional Email' which either missing of disabled.

Troubleshoot:
Check under Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Activity types if you can see 'Transactional Email'.

If you can't then add new Activity type named 'Transactional Email'

If you can see then

1. Check if its enabled.
2. Check the machine name for that activity type
   either in database or using api explorer using params shown in screenshot (civicrm/api). If you dont get result then create a new one.

[image]

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Than you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is very hard to read (I recommend always pasting the text in addition to screenshots, makes this searchable for others and easier for folks to help).  However, I can see that this is caused by your Sparkpost extension.  I would follow up with them directly.